# Nesting under the Devise in Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a problem with Controller Show Product. Can anyone help me out?

> No route matches `{:action=>"show", :controller=>"products", :id=>nil, :vendor_id=>"3"}` missing required keys: [:id]

```jsp
   <td>
     <%= link_to 'Show', vendor_product_path(current_vendor, @product) %><br>
     <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %><br>
     <%= link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
   </td>
```

my controller in product

```
  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:vendor_id])
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to find all the products for a specific vendor, it would be something like:

```
def show
  @vendor_products = Vendor.find(params[:vendor_id]).products
end
```

If you are just trying to find a single product by id:

```
def show
  # Since :id is currently nil in params, this will not work
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Im trying to do first thing, but still is not working
this are my routes

devise_for :vendors, :controllers => {:registrations => "vendors/registrations"}, :path => "accounts"

resources :vendors do
  resources :products
end

Comment: @DeanGergorić Please do not attempt to edit and remove code from an existing answer, and instead leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

In the view, where are you getting `@product` from? Seems like `@product` is not yet saved to the database, and so it is nil in the view (in the line `<%= link_to 'Show', vendor_product_path(current_vendor, @product) %>`. Which view file have you shown, and what is the corresponding controller action?

In that controller action, make sure you add a line to save the product `@product.save`

In case the @product is valid, then try passing in the fields explicitly:

`<%= link_to 'Show', vendor_product_path(:vendor_id => current_vendor.id, :id => @product) %>`